# Reading multiple images in python using only matplotlib and cv2

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I want to read multiple images from a folder and display them in my jupyter notebook. to achieve this i need to use for loop in combination with matplotlib and cv2 packages. i have tried to read the images using matplotlib and cv2 but the code seems repetitive and i have had difficulty in making a simple and more shorter code that can be easily read and understood. how can i shorten my code to be clear, readable and unrepetitive?

for example my code is as follows:

```
def bike_images(self):
    ### creating a function to generate different bike images that a customer/ or a bike rider 
    can see or visualize

    import cv2
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    ## creating a figure object

    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))

    #setting the rows and columns to display the images

    rows=2
    col=3
    #reading the images
    
    image1=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\InfinityKE\Downloads\road.webp")
    image2=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\InfinityKE\Downloads\bike3.jpg")
    image3=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\InfinityKE\Downloads\bike1.jpg")
    image4=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\InfinityKE\Downloads\gravel.webp")
    image5=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\InfinityKE\Downloads\mountain.webp")
    image6=cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\InfinityKE\Downloads\bike2.jpg")

    # Adds a subplot at the 1st position

    fig.add_subplot(rows,col,1)

    #showing images
    plt.imshow(image1)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("Road_terrain")
    # Adds a subplot at the 2nd position

    fig.add_subplot(rows,col,2)
    #showing images
    plt.imshow(image2)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("all_weather_terrain")
    # Adds a subplot at the 3rd position

    fig.add_subplot(rows,col,3)
    #showing images
    plt.imshow(image3)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("rough_terrain")
    # Adds a subplot at the 4th position

    fig.add_subplot(rows,col,4)
    #showing images
    plt.imshow(image4)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("gravel_terrain")
    # Adds a subplot at the 5th position

    fig.add_subplot(rows,col,5)
    #showing images
    plt.imshow(image5)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("mountain_terrain")
    # Adds a subplot at the 6th position

    fig.add_subplot(rows,col,6)
    #showing images
    plt.imshow(image6)
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.title("naval_terrain")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `os` library to get the all images in a folder.

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os


def bike_images():
    ### creating a function to generate different bike images that a customer/ or a bike rider

    ## creating a figure object

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))

    # setting the rows and columns to display the images

    rows = 2
    col = 3
    path = "C:\Users\InfinityKE\Downloads"
    path_list = os.listdir(path)
    for i in path_list:
        name = i.partition('.')[0]
        img_path = f'{path}\{i}'
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        fig.add_subplot(rows, col, 1)
        # showing images
        plt.axis("off")
        plt.title(f"{name}_terrain")
        plt.imshow(img)


bike_images()
```